# 3 table sql query takes 40+ seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, time, view

We do have 3 different tables;

```
  **line_item_table;**  
  item_id, description, qtty, price-

  **supplier_offer_table**  
suplier_id, suplier_name , item_id , suplier_price

**warehouse_info_table**  
item_id, in_out_info(0/1),quantity, price, warehouse_id(1 or 2)
```

I am trying to create a view with informations from that 3 tables;

```
**view**   
item_id, 
line_item_table.description, 
line_item_table.qtty, 
line_item_table.price, 
(warehouse id = 1 item quantity (in-out quatntity ) from warehouse_info_table), 
(warehouse id = 1 last price for that item_id from warehouse_info_table) , 
(warehouse id = 2 item quantity (in-out quatntity ) from warehouse_info_table), 
(warehouse id = 2 last price for that item_id  from warehouse_info_table),
(lowest price and supplier_name for that item_id from supplier_offer_table ) ,
(second lowest price and supplier_name for that item_id from supplier_offer_table ) ,
(third lowest price and supplier_name for that item_id from supplier_offer_table )
```

for 240 line items it takes around 40 seconds is there any way to decrease that time ?

Comment: Can you show the query that's taking 40+ seconds? Are there any indexes and/or foreign keys between the tables?

Comment: Use joins between the tables instead of individual select for each value desired.

Comment: Without the actual query we can't begin to help. The table definition including indexes would be a huge help too. But the query at the very least.

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Acual querry is a big mess and has inner queries and joins. i would like to learn what is the best way to write this querry if it is possible .

Comment: We can help but you haven't given us enough information to truly help. At the bare minimum we need to know the structure of the tables, some sample data and desired output. See the link above posted from TheGameiswar.